# JS Check Form before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following form:

```
<form onsubmit="return testform(tolowanswers,emptyAnswers);" class="edit_question" id="edit_question"
```

I check the Form before submit with the function testform, Is there a possibility to run a second function after testform()

thanks

Comment: what do you want to do in the new method

Comment: yes it is possible can you post your code

Comment: `return testform(tolowanswers,emptyAnswers) && secondmethod();`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call two functions on a form submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250915/how-to-call-two-functions-on-a-form-submit)

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks. will you post your comment as answer so I can mark It as solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy solution could to call the function like

```
return testform(tolowanswers,emptyAnswers) && secondmethod();
```

this will call the second function if `testform` returns true.

Another solution could to use another function like

```
onsubmit="return myfunction();"
```

then

```
function myfunction() {
    if (testfunction()) {
        secondfunction();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to put those two functions inside the onsubmit event itself like below

```
"return (testform(tolowanswers,emptyAnswers) && secondFn())"
```

It will check if the first function is true and only if it returns true, then the secondFn will be executed.

Another way would be to invoke `secondFn()` inside `testForm` function after all validation.