# Calling two function with one submit button/onsubmit

Tags: javascript

I know there are many questions about this topic but none similar to mine. so I have this new gaming website that I'm creating and I want to call for two functions that are totally different. one function that calls for the user to validate the form and the other function should display a welcome message right after validating the form.

I've tried many ways and I googled but none worked. Moreover the code isn't running although I've checked and everything is fine but still not running.

```js
function validateFormSubmission() {
  let firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
  let lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;

  if (firstName == null || firstName == "") {
    alert("First Name shouldn't be empty");
    return false;
  } else if (lastName == null || lastName == "") {
    alert("Last Name shouldn't be empty");
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

function showWelcomeMessage() {
  let firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
  let lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
  document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = 'Hey Gamer' + firstName + lastName + ', Welcome ' + '!';
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form onsubmit="return validateFormSubmission()">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Your first name-</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="firstName"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Your last name-</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lastName"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <form onclick="showWelcomeMessage()"></form>
  <input type="submit" value="Let's play" />
  <hr>
  <div id="outputDiv">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250915/how-to-call-two-functions-on-a-form-submit

Comment: why do you need two forms?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the `showWelcomeMessage()` function, if `validateFormSubmission()` returns true:

```js
function validateAndShowMessage() {
  if (validateFormSubmission()) {
    showWelcomeMessage();
  }
}

function validateFormSubmission() {
  let firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
  let lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;

  if (firstName == null || firstName == "") {
    alert("First Name shouldn't be empty");
    return false;
  } else if (lastName == null || lastName == "") {
    alert("Last Name shouldn't be empty");
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

function showWelcomeMessage() {
  let firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
  let lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
  document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = 'Hey Gamer ' + firstName + " " + lastName + ', Welcome ' + '!';
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form onsubmit="validateAndShowMessage(); return false;">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Your first name-</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="firstName"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Your last name-</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="lastName"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Let's play" />

  </form>
  <div id="outputDiv">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sure! Glad, that I helped

Answer (score 1):

You may not need two forms here, the second form is not doing anything. Also onclick handler on form is quite strange

You can actually create a [**Promise**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) inside the first function that is `validateFormSubmission` and depending on it's success or failure call the second function

```js
function validateFormSubmission() {
  // returning a promise, so depending on returned value, next step can be processed  
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
    let lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;

    if (firstName == null || firstName == "") {
      alert("First Name shouldn't be empty");
      return false;  // it can also be reject(false)
    } else if (lastName == null || lastName == "") {
      alert("Last Name shouldn't be empty");
      return false;
    } else {
      return resolve(true) // validation is successful so return true
    }
  })
}

function showWelcomeMessage() {
  let firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
  let lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
  document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = 'Hey Gamer' + firstName + lastName + ', Welcome ' + '!';
}

document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  //since button type is submit so prevent the default behavior 
  e.preventDefault();
  validateFormSubmission().then(function(x) {
    //x will be true is validation is successful
    if (x) {
      showWelcomeMessage()
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Your first name-</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="firstName"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Your last name-</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="lastName"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="submit" value="Let's play">Lets Play</button>
</form>

<hr>
<div id="outputDiv">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call the second function inside the first one and you will have your thing working.

```
    function validateFormSubmission(){
        let firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
        let lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;

        if (firstName==null || firstName==""){
            alert("First Name shouldn't be empty");
        return false;
        }

        else if (lastName==null || lastName==""){
            alert("Last Name shouldn't be empty");
        return false;
        }
        else{  
        return showWelcomeMessage();
        }
        }
        function showWelcomeMessage(){
            let firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
            let lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
            document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = 'Hey Gamer' + firstName + lastName + ', Welcome ' + '!';
            return true;
        }
```